# Are protocol implementations also tested as part of FIPS certification?

Tags: certification, fips, nist

I just went to CMVP website and opened a random FIPS certificate.

https://csrc.nist.gov/Projects/Cryptographic-Module-Validation-Program/Certificate/2898

In the FIPS certificate, FIPS algorithms like AES, DRBG, RSA etc are listed which are listed there after testing the implementation. It also lists CVL which has protocol stuff like IKE, TLS etc. Are protocol implementations also tested as part of FIPS certification?